# QRegularExpression match position in the source string

Tags: c++, qt

For example I have a QString, and I do the search for mathes in a while. How can I retrieve the position at which the match was in the source string?

```
QString str = ...;
QRegularExpression re(...);
int pos = 0;
QRegularExpressionMatch match;
while ((match = re.match(str, pos)).hasMatch()) {
    setting new pos somehow
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatch.html :

> In addition, QRegularExpressionMatch returns the substrings captured by the capturing groups in the pattern string. The implicit capturing group with index 0 captures the result of the whole match.
>
> For each captured substring it is possible to query its starting and ending offsets in the subject string by calling the **capturedStart**() and the **capturedEnd**() function, respectively. The length of each captured substring is available using the capturedLength() function.

Example:

```
QRegularExpression re("\\d+");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match("XYZabc123defXYZ");
if (match.hasMatch()) {
    int startOffset = match.capturedStart(); // startOffset == 6
    int endOffset = match.capturedEnd(); // endOffset == 9
    // ...
}
```

Comment: As I understand, these functions return offsets in the matched substring, aren't they?

Comment: No, they return the offsets of the matched substring relative to the entire subject string.

Comment: Added an example for clarity.